# Seamlessly and efficiently flipping numpy array or sparse matrix along all axes

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

Let's say we have a matrix (numpy array) of unknown shape, the shape can be for example `(1,5)` (row), `(5,1)` (column), `(5,5)` (square), `(5,6)` (non-square) or `(5,)` (degenerated) (ok the last case isn't a matrix but is a valid input).

I would like to given a matrix of any shape (column, row, square, nonsquare, degenerated). I will return a flipped up/down left/right version of it.

Since `np.flip` has some issues with 1d arrays. My approach was:

```
def flipit(M):
    return M.ravel()[::-1].reshape(M.shape)
```

It works, but is that acceptable? Any faster ways to do it?

In the other hand, how can I do the same for sparse matrices (for example if `M` is `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`).

Comment: >>> z = np.arange(5)  >>> np.flip(np.atleast_1d(z))   would work as well

Comment: seems `np.flip` works well with N-D arrays, just `fliplr` and `flipud` has some dimensionality issues. Amyway good to know the `np.atleast_K-d`.

Comment: In fact comparing performance of `np.flip` and the `ravel` method in the OP, both have similar performance. (for small matrices)

Comment: @Lin I benchmarked your approach with `np.fliplr(np.flipud(M))`. Your solution seems to be 3 orders of magnitude faster. So, I guess that's the best way to go.

Comment: @kmario23 I have evaluated large matrices too. both methods are equivalent (by large I mean 100000x10000).

Comment: @Lin Even for such larger arrays `np.fliplr(np.flipud(M))` executes in microsecs whereas your approach executes in nanosecs.

Comment: @kmario23 yes. :-D

Comment: If the flip produces a view, it will be fast.  But if at some point it has to make a copy, it will be slower.  And sometimes an action following the flip will force a copy.  A common case is a transpose followed by a ravel.  So don't put too much weight on flip timings (in isolation).

Comment: When evaluating the result of these operations, look at the `.__array_interface__` dicitonary (or at least the `strides`).  Work out, for yourself, why strides change, and how the data buffer address changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use slice notation with a step-size of `-1`  for the number of dims in the input to flip along all the axes, as that's what the original code is essentially doing. This would cover both arrays and sparse matrices -

```
def flip_allaxes(a): # a can be array or sparse matrix
    # generate flipping slice
    sl = slice(None,None,-1) # or np.s_[::-1] suggested by @kmario23
    return a[tuple([sl]*a.ndim)]
```

**Simplified on newer NumPy versions (15.1 onwards)**

On newer NumPy versions : [`Version 15.1` and newer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/release.html#np-flip-can-operate-over-multiple-axes), that allows us to specify tuple of ints for the axes along which the flipping is needed. For the default case with `axis=None` from the [`docs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html), it flips along all axes. Thus, to solve our case, it would be simply `np.flip(a)` and this would again cover both generic ndarrays and sparse matrices.

Comment: Nice! This approach seems to be ~ 200 ns faster than OP's approach :)

Comment: I feel that `np.s_[::-1]` is lot more intuitive while being equivalent to your solution. It'd be nice to add this. But it's little restrictive (i.e. works only for 2D arrays).